# Add whole JSON object to ArrayList

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

I got this object using a HttpGet request that I'd like to add to an ArrayList with more objects. What would be the correct way to parse the whole object add it to the array?

```
{
  "serial_number": "446D57D42F38",
  "name": "Garage Door",
  "accessories": [
    {
      "obfuscated": false,
      "target_state": "closed",
      "current_state": "opening",
      "name": "Garage Door Opener",
      "locked": false
    },
    {
      "hue": 55.5,
      "saturation": 85.5,
      "name": "Light Bulb",
      "power": true,
      "brightness": 95
    }
  ]
}
```

Code:

```
List<String> accessories = new ArrayList<String>();

HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream content = entity.getContent();
InputStreamReader text = new InputStreamReader(content, "UTF-8");
accessories.add(text.toString())
```

Comment: why not use jsonarray? and you can use EntityUtils to get the string-json directlty

Comment: @Nikhil I'm on it, thanks for information!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instantiate a JSONArray and then create a for loop. Call the objects inside the jsonarray inside the loop.