# How to make a Arraylist with JSON Objects in JAVA?

Tags: java, json, arraylist

I want to make a `Arraylist` with `JSON Objects` .

There is a loop which gives me `JSON Objects`. I want to put them into a `ArrayList`.

Here is the Code which gives me `JSON Objects`. Please let me know how to put all the values ito a `ArrayList`

```java
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    String datapointsBodyString = "{items:[{id:" + unionUptimeMetadata.getLatencyTimeseriesIds().get(i) + ", start: " + oldestTimeString + ",end: " + now + ", granularity: 1m}]}";
    JSONObject datapointsBodyObject = new JSONObject((datapointsBodyString));

    HttpResponse uptimeResponse = httpService.POST("url", datapointsBodyObject.toString(), unionUptimeTimeseriesHeaders);
    HttpEntity uptimeResponseEntity = uptimeResponse.getEntity();
    String uptimeResponseString = EntityUtils.toString(uptimeResponseEntity);
    JSONObject uptimeResponsObject = new JSONObject(uptimeResponseString);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this, it could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25824606/10715479

Comment: Thanks @DavidDíaz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally worth doing a search for common programming tasks. You could just google search "java add to list" which should result in something like:

```
List<JSONObject> myList = new ArrayList<>();

myList.add(uptimeResponsObject);
```

that should be enough for you to get it working.